# PostgreSQL: refcursor and portal name

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.6, database-cursor

As we know, PostgreSQL has `refcursors`. I understand them as reference to cursor, i.e. if

```
DECLARE
  _var refcursor;
```

than it can store name for portal:

```
_var = 'cursor_name_1';
```

We can use it and change name later:

```
_var = 'cursor_name_2'; --now same variable will reference to another portal
```

We can fetch from refcursor variable:

```
FETCH ALL FROM _var;
```

or use portal's name:

```
FETCH ALL FROM "cursor_name_1"; --double-quoted
```

---

Questions:

**Q1.** Why can't I write

```
FETCH ALL FROM 'cursor_name_1'; --string literal (single-quoted)
```

but I can use:

```
_var = 'cursor_name_1'
```

**Q2.** What type of clause does PostgreSQL expect in `FETCH FROM`?

**Q3.** What does the double-quoted portal name `"cursor_name_1"` mean, if it can be used in `FETCH FROM`, but can't be used in an assignment?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, strings in single quotes are *string constants* (also known as *string literals*), while strings in double quotes are *quoted identifiers*, that is, names for objects like tables, columns … or cursors.

Don't mix up those two things.

Each cursor has a name, by which you have to refer to it in SQL. That's why you need to use double quotes in the SQL statement `FETCH`.

In PL/pgSQL, you can have a variable of type `refcursor`. Now if you assign a string literal to the variable, you are setting the *name* of the cursor. That is the source of your confusion, and I admin that it *is* confusing.

Comment: Do you mean that `FETCH ALL` has 2 different variants: 1st takes name of portal and 2nd takes refcursor variable which contains name of portal?

Comment: Don't mix up the SQL command `FETCH` (with identifier) and PL/pgSQL `FETCH` (requires a PL/pgSQL variable.